# Dropwizard 0.8.0 WADL support

Tags: jersey-2.0, dropwizard, wadl

Wadl can be configured in Dropwizard 0.7.1 like this:

```
environment
        .jersey()
        .getResourceConfig()
        .getProperties()
        .put(ResourceConfig.FEATURE_DISABLE_WADL, Boolean.FALSE);//Create WADL
```

How can I set it in Dropwizard 0.8.0

Comment: I think WADL is enabled by default in Jersey 2. See [Configuration](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/wadl.html#d0e13101). In general, to set a property, you can just use [`jersey().property(...)`](https://github.com/dropwizard/dropwizard/blob/master/dropwizard-jersey/src/main/java/io/dropwizard/jersey/setup/JerseyEnvironment.java#L87)

Comment: Then is this correct?

  environment
    .jersey()
    .getResourceConfig()
    .getProperties()
    .put("jersey.config.server.wadl.disableWadl", Boolean.TRUE);

Comment: You are disabling the feature with that. I thought you want it enabled.

Comment: I want to configure it via my config file

Comment: Well, the `Configuration` is passed into the `run` method, along with the `Environment`. I don't see why you can't put the value into the configuration file. If you're looking for something built in to dropwizard, I don't see anything, [but you can check again](https://dropwizard.github.io/dropwizard/manual/configuration.html#all). If it's not there, you can always make a request

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The location of the property key has changed and the map is unmodifiable - so you'll need to use the `addProperties` method instead:

```java
import org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerProperties;
...
Map<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<>();
properties.put(ServerProperties.WADL_FEATURE_DISABLE, false);
environment.jersey().getResourceConfig().addProperties(properties);
```

And as of 0.8.0 [Dropwizard is disabling WADL generation](https://github.com/dropwizard/dropwizard/blob/master/dropwizard-jersey/src/main/java/io/dropwizard/jersey/DropwizardResourceConfig.java) so you'll need to turn it on explicitly.

Answer (score 1):

```java
import org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerProperties;
...
environment.jersey().disable(ServerProperties.WADL_FEATURE_DISABLE);
```

Comment: How and why, exactly, does this code answer the question? Could you please add some context?